# How to retrieve AWS ServiceCatalog Portfolio id and Product ID

Tags: aws-cdk

Using AWS CDK anyone have ideas how to retrieve the portfolio id and product id that is deployed via AWS CDK,

I'm attempting to perform an association between product and portfolio via code referencing https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_servicecatalog/CfnPortfolioProductAssociation.html

Any pointers would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

[CfnCloudFormationProduct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-servicecatalog.CfnCloudFormationProduct.html) and [CfnPortfolio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-servicecatalog.CfnPortfolio.html) both allow access to their IDs through `.ref`.

IE, when creating a `CfnPortfolioProductAssociation`.

```py
portfolio = CfnPortfolioProductAssociation(self, "Porfolio", my_param=xxx)
product = CfnCloudFormationProduct(self, "Product", my_param=xxx)
CfnPortfolioProductAssociation(self, "Association", portfolio_id=portfolio.ref, product_id=product.ref, ...)
```

This is the equivalent of "{ Ref: ResourceName }" in cloudformation. This can resolve to different things for different constructs, but usually its the ID of the resource. You can see what Ref returns for each CFN resource in the [CFN Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-servicecatalog-cloudformationprovisionedproduct.html#aws-resource-servicecatalog-cloudformationprovisionedproduct-return-values)